# Running function from another file using window[]

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a simple ajax helper, that runs all my ajax requests, that is seperate in a file, with the following code:

https://pastebin.com/raw/XQE0xgPD

In that file I am calling my functions like so:

```
window[proSettings.afterAjax](data, $this);
```

That gets the function name passed through from

```
 afterAjax
```

Okay, so in another file, let's say test.js, which contains some jquery to run my ajax function

```
$('#create-entry').on('submit', function () {
    $(this).proAjax({
        'afterAjax': 'createdTest',
        'alertElement': 'success-message', 
    });
    return false;
});

var createdTest = function(data)
{
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

Now, when I submit a form, it submits fine until it gets to the `window` function, which throws an error:

```
TypeError: window[proSettings.afterAjax] is not a function
```

But the function passed through that does exist, when I console log the `proSettings.afterAjax` it sends back `createdTest` as I'd expect.

Now, if I run the code above `create-entry` one in a html file it works how I expect it to work. It just doesn't work if that code is in an external.js file.

Any ideas of how I could fix this?

Comment: It is better not to put your global functions/variable on the window. If you want to set it on window anyway in order to be able to use it global set it on some namespace object which you set on the window. i.e. `window.namespace = { };` and the `window.namespace.myFunc = function () { }`

Comment: Did you include both files?

Comment: Use conditional break point `typeof window[proSettings.afterAjax] !== "function"` to catch the issue, or just log that case. There is no magic I believe...

Comment: window.createdTest = function(data)

Comment: Yes mohammad, the link is one one called core.js and the code posted is another.js called external.js core.js is loaded first

Comment: @epascarello that worked doing window.createdTest = function(data) Thank you very very much :)